# XRDP connection to Raspberry Pi suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, xrdp

I have just reinstalled my raspberry pi.

I set SSH, and through this installed XRDP with `sudo apt install xrdp`

Added a new user with `sudo adduser USERNAME`

From here on I could connect with Windows Remote Desktop Connection.

Things worked smoothly, until I suddenly wasn't able to connect anymore.

I've tried to remove XRDP with `sudo apt purge xrdp` and subsequent reinstallation to no avail.

SSH connection still works.

i don't know what else you might need to know, but any help is apreciated.

Comment: Check the logs in `/var/log` for any issues with xrdp

Comment: The solution was simply to reinstall the OS :)
I'll look for the logs if it happens again, thank you

Comment: `I have just reinstalled my raspberry pi.` ... `The solution was simply to reinstall the OS` ... odd